# AngularJS: Object inheritance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have multiple directives that will be creating different objects, but each of these objects will share a lot of the same properties so I really want to have a base object that they can inherit from. How would i go about doing this? Is there a way to create an object so any directive will have access to it and then be able to just inherit off it when the directives are creating new objects themselves?

```
app.directive('addtext', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, model) {

            element.on('click', function (e) {      
                var testObject = {
                Id: '1',
                value: 1,
                inputType: 'textarea',
                label: 'Question',
                required: "false",
                placeholder: 'Placeholder',
                helpMessage: null,
                textAreaSize: 5
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Ideally here test object would only really need to contain inputtype and textareasize. Everything else would be held in another object. I'm just not sure how to do this in relation to directives.

Comment: IMO create a factory that is a model that you inject into each directive.

Comment: I have heard no other way of doing this apart from what @ajmajmajma says. So I would agree with that

Comment: One option would be using require.js on top of your angular project.

Comment: If you really need inheritance of objects read about [`angular.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Comment: Ah that's great. I had no idea about that method. I now have my model in a separate service and then inherit it that way, making it simple.

Answer (score 0):

So you could set a service in between everything where you essentially are just putting your data in one place

```
.service('mySharedService', [
        '$q',
        function($q) {

           this.id = {
             get value() {
               return this.id;
             },
             set value(id) {
               this.id = id;
             }
          };
      }
 ]);
```

So this is just a quick proof of concept, but the idea is you would inject that into each and do a get or set on whatever you need and it would be shared inside that service between all of them.